# Greedy algorithm in C _cashier

Tags: c, cs50, greedy

I am currently taking Harvard's CS50 - Introduction to cs and I have no previous coding experiences. So ı am kind of having a hard time with the assignments.

The main purpose of my code is to calculate the minimum number of coins( 25, 10, 5, and 1) used for a given amount of cash. Besides, I have to convert dollars to cents. Here is my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)
{

int change = 0;

 float dollars = get_float("Change: ");
 int cents = round( dollars * 100);  

while ( 0 > dollars ) 
; 
   
{
    if ( cents >= 25)
    {
        cents = cents - 25;
        change++;
    }
    else if ( cents >= 10)
    {
        cents = cents - 10;
        change ++;
    }
    else if ( cents >= 5)
    {
        cents = cents - 5;
        change++;
    }
    else if ( cents >= 1)
    {
        cents = cents - 1;
        change++;
    }
    printf("%i\n" , change);
}
}
```

unfortunately, ı cannot find where the bug is. When I type "5" it gives me the number "1" However, when ı type 0.25 it also gives me the result "1". Can anyone help?

Comment: That `while` loop is broken in at least one way. The `;` after it ends the loop, so nothing is inside of the `while` loop. That would normally cause your program to hang indefinitely, but the condition appears to be backwards, so it never runs. If you fix those two issues, that may fix your problem.

Comment: When your code doesn't work, **try something simpler.** Try writing a program that uses a `while` loop to print asterisks, so that when you type "4", it prints "****". Once that works perfectly, modify it to accept a number of cents, and print the number of 25-cent pieces that can go into it, so that when you type "315", it prints "12". Once that works perfectly, try {25, 10}, so that when you type "315", it prints "13". Build up step by step, and **never add to code that doesn't work.**

Comment: Thanks a lot!!  I should probably embrace the motto "never add to code that does not work". You guys are literally the best :) <3

Comment: @Cansu25 It's a good habit to write code incrementally. Write some code, test it, and move on when it works as you expect. Then write more code, test it, and move on when it works as you expect. That way, when it starts breaking, you know that it's caused either directly or indirectly by whatever code you just wrote.